# A little problem with a program that has an array and two functions is random but it shouldnt be

Tags: c++, arrays, function

```
bool sal_sk(int sal) //  If sal is a composite figure, then  true, if its not then false.
{ 

    for (int i = 2; i <= sal; i++) {
        if (sal%i == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;


    }
}

int lkd(int a, int b) // Checks the gcd 
{ 
    int c;
    while (b > 0) 
    {
        c = b;
        b = a % b;
        a = c;
    }
    return a;

}

int main() 
{
    int ok;

    do 
    {
        int n;//Number of elements 
        int*a; //Given number array variable

        cout << "Put in the number of elements" << endl;
        std::cin >> n;

        a = new int[n];

        cout << "Enter the array elements" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            std::cin >> *a;
        }
        int rez = a[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            if (sal_sk(a[i] == true))
                rez = lkd(rez, a[i]);

        }
        delete[] a;
        cout << "Composite figure gcd is  " << rez << endl;

        cout << " Do you want to continue(1) or to end (0)?" << endl;
        cin >> ok;// Asks the user to enter in if he wants to continue or to end

    }   while (ok == 1);
}
```

Hey guys, I have two functions that check the greatest common divisor of composite figures in an array but it is random and idk why.
For Example if I enter 3 elements 4 6 9 it sometimes prints out that the gcd is 3 but sometimes it prints out that it is 1 which is correct but it happens at random times,and if I enter 9 4 6 it says that the gcd is 2, i just dont understand.Thanks in advance

Comment: There isn't really a point to having a `for` loop that always `return`s on the first iteration. What did you intend for that function to actually do? You probably don't want to *necessarily* return on the first iteration.

Comment: `bool sal_sk(int sal)`  returns true if sal is even false if it is not. It does not for the reason @FrançoisAndrieux mentioned. You probably want to move the return false out of the loop and change the `for (int i = 2; i <= sal; i++) {` to `for (int i = 2; i < sal; i++) {`

Comment: Hey that function is intented to return true when the number is composite and false when it is not, I dont understand why it is always true tho :/

Comment: Okay that seems to helped a bit, could you check the `lkd` function because for example when I enter 17 2 4 it should return that gcd is 2 but it returns 1

Comment: `if (sal_sk(a[i] == true))` does not make sense to me. It passes a boolean to sal_sk()

Answer (score 0):

bool sal_sk(int sal) returns true if sal is even false if it is not because you return always on the first iteration of your loop as @FrançoisAndrieux mentioned.

```
bool sal_sk(int sal) //  If sal is a composite figure, then  true, if its not then false.
{ 

    for (int i = 2; i <= sal; i++) {
        if (sal%i == 0)
            return true; 
        else
            return false;


    }
}
```

To return true on composite make the following changes.

```
bool sal_sk(int sal) //  If sal is a composite figure, then  true, if its not then false.
{ 

    for (int i = 2; i < sal; i++) {
        if (sal%i == 0)
            return true;   // Has some factor other than 1 and itself
    }
    return false; // Does not have a factor other than 1 and itself
}
```

Another bug is here:

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    if (sal_sk(a[i] == true))
        rez = lkd(rez, a[i]);

}
```

This code passes `true` or `false` to `sal_sk()` depending on if `a[i] !=0`

Instead you want:

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    if (sal_sk(a[i]))
        rez = lkd(rez, a[i]);
}
```

This is also a bug:

```
cout << "Enter the array elements" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    std::cin >> *a; // This puts the value in a[0] always!
}
```

The code should be:

```
cout << "Enter the array elements" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    std::cin >> a[i]; // Put the value in the array at index i
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The code here:

```
    cout << "Enter the array elements" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cin >> *a;
    }
```

does not fill in all the array elements, but instead just overwrites the first entry.

This is far from the only problem with your code. In particular, `sal_sk` is not doing whatever you think its doing.

Comment: It should be `std::cin>>a[]` ?

Comment: It should be std::cin >> a[i].